# Moving to Next Screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

[If i click on Lungs Banks i want to move to another screen How can i do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LJE0.png)

```
<KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
  <WelcomeStyledContainer>
    <StatusBar style="dark" />
    <OrganHeading>
      <OrganHeadingText>Donate Able Organ</OrganHeadingText>
    </OrganHeading>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.Box}>
        <View style={styles.inerBox}>
          <CardStyle>
            <CardImage source={require('./../assets/organImage/lungs.png')} />
            <CardText>Lungs Bank</CardText>
          </CardStyle>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution will work for you if you are using React-navigation.

UI Screen:

```
<CardText onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("YOUR SCREEN NAME HERE")}>Lungs Bank</CardText>
```

Card Text Component:

```
const CardText = ({onPress}) => {
return <Text onPress={onPress}>{props.children}</Text>;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)
library to get started with navigation in react-native.